# Which node can provide transactions in block 0?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, parity, infura

We are building a data-analytics [platform](http://analyseether.com/) for ethereum transactions. I am using both a local Parity node and an Infura Geth node but cannot find the transactions that occurred at block 0.

Etherscan tells me that block 0 has [8893](https://etherscan.io/txs?block=0) transactions, but these transactions are not available in both the nodes.

**Result from Infura node**

```
>>> from ethjsonrpc import InfuraEthJsonRpc
>>> c = InfuraEthJsonRpc(network='mainnet')
>>> block_data = c.eth_getBlockByNumber(0)
>>> block_data 
{u'nonce': u'0x0000000000000042', u'receiptsRoot': u'0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421', u'hash': u'0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3', u'uncles': [], u'timestamp': u'0x0', u'sha3Uncles': u'0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347', u'miner': u'0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', u'parentHash': u'0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000', u'extraData': u'0x11bbe8db4e347b4e8c937c1c8370e4b5ed33adb3db69cbdb7a38e1e50b1b82fa', u'gasLimit': u'0x1388', u'number': u'0x0', u'stateRoot': u'0xd7f8974fb5ac78d9ac099b9ad5018bedc2ce0a72dad1827a1709da30580f0544', u'difficulty': u'0x400000000', u'transactionsRoot': u'0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421', u'size': u'0x21c', u'transactions': [], u'mixHash': u'0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000', u'totalDifficulty': u'0x400000000', u'gasUsed': u'0x0', u'logsBloom': u'0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'}
```

**Result from Parity node**

```
>>> from ethjsonrpc import ParityEthJsonRpc
>>> c = ParityEthJsonRpc()
>>> block_data = c.eth_getBlockByNumber(0)
>>> block_data
{u'transactionsRoot': u'0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421', u'gasLimit': u'0x1388', u'number': u'0x0', u'size': u'0x21c', u'author': u'0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', u'mixHash': u'0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000', u'sha3Uncles': u'0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347', u'miner': u'0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', u'logsBloom': u'0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000', u'nonce': u'0x0000000000000042', u'hash': u'0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3', u'uncles': [], u'transactions': [], u'timestamp': u'0x0', u'sealFields': [u'0xa00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000', u'0x880000000000000042'], u'receiptsRoot': u'0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421', u'difficulty': u'0x400000000', u'parentHash': u'0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000', u'extraData': u'0x11bbe8db4e347b4e8c937c1c8370e4b5ed33adb3db69cbdb7a38e1e50b1b82fa', u'stateRoot': u'0xd7f8974fb5ac78d9ac099b9ad5018bedc2ce0a72dad1827a1709da30580f0544', u'totalDifficulty': u'0x400000000', u'gasUsed': u'0x0'}
```

Generally, the transaction information is appended after the block information. None of the nodes give transactions that occurred at block 0 in the response.

Where can I get this information? I would prefer scraping this data from an ethereum node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the reply to this question on Gitter so posting the results here:

1. There were no transactions in block 0.
2. The results from both the nodes are the canonical truths
3. The genesis state of ethereum started with few account balances.
4. "The genesis block has a bunch of balances; I assume Etherscan has implemented its own 'virtual transactions' to balance the books."

The balances of the genesis state can be found [here](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/blob/master/ethcore/res/ethereum/foundation.json#L2797)